# Can QGIS Measure Line tool compute correct geodetic distance?

Tags: qgis, distance, measurements

As I understood, this tool normally shows distance in the project CRS units, not the geodetic meters (despite it actually says the distance is in meters).

However, [now I read](http://www.baruch.cuny.edu/geoportal/practicum/gis_prac_2.html) (Section III, 4 - Measure some distances) that in the *Measure Tool Options* you can change the "Ellipsoid for distance calculation":

[image]

Does it mean it can actually finally compute correct geodetic distance?

However, I don't see this option in the QGIS ver 1.9.0-Master.